# PHP - Mysql_num_rows on result in function (OOP)

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying with some OOP and got a problem with making a mysql_num_rows on a query in a function. I got a function looking like this:

```
    function userPush()
{
    $sql = ("SELECT *
                FROM pushComments
                WHERE pushCommentsFromProfileId='$_SESSION[userId]'
            ");
    $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    $userPush = Array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):

        $userPush[$row['pushCommentsId']]['pushCommentsId'] = $row['pushCommentsId'];
        $userPush[$row['pushCommentsId']]['pushCommentsTimestamp'] = $row['pushCommentsTimestamp'];
        $userPush[$row['pushCommentsId']]['pushCommentsFromProfile'] = $row['pushCommentsFromProfile'];
        $userPush[$row['pushCommentsId']]['pushCommentsFromProfileId'] = $row['pushCommentsFromProfileId'];
        $userPush[$row['pushCommentsId']]['pushCommentsContent'] = $row['pushCommentsContent'];

    endwhile;

    return $userPush;
}
//
```

And calling the function like this:

```
$db -> New woko();
$pushComments = $db->pushComments();
```

How would I create a mysql_num_rows here? Can I call a $count variable from the function, and how?

Comment: Can you not just use the count() function on the returned array?

Comment: ofc.. didnt even think of that.. im tired :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this since the data that is being returned is an array

$db -> New woko();

$pushComments = $db->pushComments();

$pushCommentsCount = count($db->pushComments());

hope that helps

Comment: That's not very optimal code as (a) you're making two calls to the db for the same info, and (b) you could possible get a different count back if row(s) are added to the table between the first and second calls. Better to do $pushCommentsCount = count($pushComments);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do count(var) to get the total number of items on your array (seen as the first index is the unique ID.

just add this line to the bottom of your script

```
$num_rows = count($pushComments);
```

Comment: and how would you call a var from the function? how would you call $num_rows?

Comment: I'm confused, $num_rows is an integer number due to it holding the result from count.... Maybe I'm not understanding what your question is, could you please rephrase it?